# How can I get the order ID in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I retrieve the order ID in WooCommerce?

Comment: Just to clarify: `order id` equals to `post id`, as found into Wordpress standard tables. `order number` is the code that represent WooCommerce's order as represented in WC tables.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

it worked. Just modified it

```
global $woocommerce, $post;

$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

//to escape # from order id 

$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
```

Comment: I just tried - `$order->get_order_number()` and it returned only the id ( There wasn't any # ). I didn't need to replace that #.

Probably latest woocommerce update removed the #. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that `$order->get_order_number()` only returns the id (there is no "#" character) since at least Woocommerce version 2.4 (up to and including 3.0 and higher).  It can be overridden by plugins with a wordpress filter, `woocommerce_order_number` so it is best to assume it is for display only and might not be numeric. Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to get ordered product instock information using $order object?

Answer (score 63):

#### Current method:

The current way of accomplishing this is by using this function:

```
$order->get_id();
```

That should return the order id without "#".

#### Old method:

In older versions of WooCommerce, you may need to access it as a property instead:

```
echo $order->id;
```

Comment: This returns the ID of the order post, not the ID of the order. $order->get_order_number(); is the correct answer.

Comment: When you search for something similar at Google this is the first post.
`$order->id` isn't anymore supported, you will get error (Member has protected access).

But if you want to get ID (not order number) you can do it with:
`$order->get_id();`

Comment: This is not working in the current version of Woocommerce, you should use $order->get_id(); like emilushi said.

Comment: My answer was from 3 and a half years ago, for an answer that is, as of now, 4 years old. Hopefully woocommerce evolved and things had changed :). Just edited my answer to reflect the current solution. Thanks for pointing out the current way of doing this.

Comment: where do you define $order??

Answer (score 14):

I didnt test it and dont know were you need it, but:

```
$order = new WC_Order(post->ID);
echo $order->get_order_number();
```

Let me know if it works.
I belive order number echoes with the "#" but you can split that if only need only the number.

Comment: I did this before, it does't work, the problem is what must be in WC_Order for parameter, I think i must delete the cookie then reduce stock manually.

Comment: (post->ID) what it will give ?

Answer (score 6):

```
$order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
```

If you

```
echo $order->id;
```

then you'll be returned the id of the post from which the order is made. As you've already got that, it's probably not what you want.

```
echo $order->get_order_number();
```

will return the id of the order (with a # in front of it). To get rid of the #,

```
echo trim( str_replace( '#', '', $order->get_order_number() ) );
```

as per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

As of woocommerce 3.0

```
$order->id;
```

will not work, it will generate notice, use getter function:

```
$order->get_id();
```

The same applies for other woocommerce objects like procut.

Answer (score 0):

As LoicTheAztec mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182262/4638682

You get get this in several ways, within several template. Like so:

```
$order_id = absint( get_query_var('view-order') );
```