# Woocommerce: Get order id after checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I have purchased the Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin and i want to be able to get the order ID in checkout page. 
I want this, because when a subscription is about to end, an email with a payment link is sent to the customer and an order is automatically added. When customer clicks the link, it redirects to the checkout page in order to pay for the order. 
I need the order ID to retrieve meta data from the specific order using some function like wc_get_order_item_meta().

Comment: The order ID assume with be in the URL params? If it's in the docs please look for yourself. https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/

Comment: @MattTheNinja  The order ID is in the URL params of the "Pay now" link contained in the email sent to the customer. But when you click this link, it redirects to the checkout page with no params in the URL. It would be a nice idea to get the order ID from this link, but i don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: IS **NOT POSSIBLE TO GET THE ORDER ID IN CHECKOUT PAGE** … IT DOESN'T EXIST YET. So I have changed the thread title a bit regarding answers in here and make it as a duplicated thread of an existing one.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question of the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633120/2540235. Note that the accepted answer for the linked question does NOT work here.

Answer (score 7):

You can get it like this:

```
    global $wp;
    $order_id = $wp->query_vars['order-pay'];
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: That's just the way to get the order id. Then the id is the used to populate the order. If you have some specific questions, I'll try to answer.

Comment: If on the "thankyou.php" page then use: $order_id = $wp->query_vars['order-received'];

Comment: Thank you...@ababak

Answer (score 1):

This is stored in the [`WC_Order`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) class as a property. This means you can use:

```
WC()->order->id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when i execute   
  `echo WC()->order->id;`  
 , i get this notice:  "Trying to get property of non-object".  @rnevius

Answer (score 1):

Get an order at the checkout page, mmmm, don't think an order exists at this point, only a cart.