# Tracking number shortcode to be used on Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, email-notifications

I am using [WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-admin-custom-order-fields/) plugin to create a custom field for tracking number. 
I was using the following code to create a shortcode that I was including to order completed email notification:

```
// [tracking_number]
function tracking_number_func( $atts ){
    global $post;
    $order_id2 = $post->ID;
    return get_post_meta( $order_id2, '_wc_acof_2', true );
    // https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-admin-custom-order-fields/
}
add_shortcode( 'tracking_number', 'tracking_number_func' );
```

But it's not working now after updating WooCommerce. I am not sure which version change made it un-useable.

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Where exactly are you using this shortcode on order completed email notification?

Comment: I am using it with "Email Customizer" plug-in and the short code is for "complete email"

Answer (score 1):

There is no post object for email notifications. Depending on where you are using this shortcode, try:

```
function wc_get_tracking_number( $atts ){
    global $order;

    return get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_wc_acof_2', true );
}
add_shortcode( 'tracking_number', 'wc_get_tracking_number' );

// USAGE: [tracking_number]
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Untested, it could work.

Comment: I tried your code and it did not work sadly. After I update the order to complete it went to blank screen to URL "https://myURL.com/wp-admin/post.php" and the email didn't get send out. I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633120/how-can-i-get-the-order-id-in-woocommerce but by replacing `$order_id2 = $post->ID;` from my own code to `$order->get_id();` didn't work either. same blank page and no email get send out. BTW thank you for taking your time

Comment: @dunkaroo This code can't work with your plugin… It only works through normal related hooks and related WooCommerce templates.

Comment: The code did work before the update, I was wondering if the API get changed or what not. I will do some more experiment and googling. If I found a answer I will post back here for people might have a similar problem. Thanks :)