# How can I get the WooCommerce order id from current order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to receive the current order id within a custom class. First, I'm checking if I'm on a view-order page. If yes, I'm trying to receive the id. The problem is, that the returned id is `19` but it should be `6456`, really strange. I'm initializing my class in my `functions.php` of my child theme:

```
public function __construct() {
    if ( is_view_order_page() ) {
        error_log( get_the_ID() );
    }
}
```

Does someone has an idea how I can solve this?

**Update:**

Another idea I had was to read the request uri which is the following:

```
https://localhost/dashboard/view-order/6264/
```

So I came out with this idea:

```
public function __construct() {
    if ( is_view_order_page() ) {
        $uri_path     = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
        $uri_segments = explode( '/', $uri_path );

        error_log(  $uri_segments[3] );
    }
}
```

But this is not that safe and good I think. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try this solution to get the order ID? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27963922/3623080

Comment: This is exactly what the `get_the_ID()` function does I think. I only skipped the part getting the order because I can't even get the right ID https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
public function __construct() {
    if ( is_view_order_page() ) {
        global $wp;
        $order_id = wc_clean( $wp->query_vars['view-order'] );
        $_order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        // some logic

        error_log(  $_order->get_id() );
    }
}
```

I checked. It's work fine