# How can I get the order ID from the order Key in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, orders

How do I retrieve the order ID from the order KEY in WooCommerce? (PHP code)

e.g.

I have the order KEY which looks like 'wc_order_qkTc2RVyGtVil' and I want to get the order ID which looks like '1950'.

background:
I only get an link which contains the order KEY. Thats why I cant use the order OBJECT to get the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Order Received, Order Pay and View Order pages, you can get the order id from URL like:

1). On Order Received (Thankyou) page:

```
$order_id = absint( get_query_var('order-received') );
```

2). On Order Pay page:

```
$order_id = absint( get_query_var('order-pay') );
```

3). On View Order pages:

```
$order_id = absint( get_query_var('view-order') );
```

Now you can use `wc_get_order_id_by_order_key()` WooCommerce function like:

```
$order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $order_key );
```

Comment: Was looking really long for this. It's not mentioned in the WC docs at all. Many thanks